# How to print floating with 2 decimals using cout in C++

Tags: c++, stl, stdout

I only see how to do it using printf:

printf(" salary = %.2f" , salary) ;

But how to specify it in standard cout function? Do any coders know?

Comment: What it has to do with STL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cout<< fixed <<setprecision(2)<< result<<endl ;
```

This is the right answer - fixed must be there!

Answer (score 2):

`std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << salary;`

More here:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/

You might want to check out the rest of the iomanip stuff too:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/

Comment: Please don't use cplusplus.com references. Use [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) instead

Comment: Feel free to use cplusplus.com references, if you prefer it.

Comment: @P0W : Any particular reason why?  I don't mind hearing a technical reason to prefer one over the other.

Comment: @Joe I'll direct you to a [post](http://kera.name/articles/2013/02/cplusplus-com-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/) from a reputed SO user [Lightness Races in Orbit](http://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit) and I totally agree with it. Rest is your point of view !

Comment: @P0W:  Ah, so it's a bit like the Herbert Schildt books... Got it.  (Ref:  http://www.seebs.net/c/c_tcn4e.html )

Comment: you forgot 'fixed' before setprecision(2)

Answer (score 1):

Use cout.precision()

eg.

```
 int main ()
 {
 cout.precision(5);
 double i = 1.23556456123;
 cout << i;
 }
```